# JS: Removing event listeners with handlers that take arguments

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I understand how an event listener is removed, however, what to do if I want to remove a handler that takes arguments?

Let's say I have a handler:

```
function handler(param1, param2){
    // do stuff with param1, param2
}
```

And I add the above handler via a wrapper function to a DOM node

```
domNode.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // invoking the handler here with arguments
    handler(this.style.color, this.style.backgroundColor);
}
```

How do I go about removing the likes of the above listener?

Cheers

Comment: `handler` is not technically a "handler", rather, it's a `function` whose name is `handler`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use an anonymous function.  You'll have to use a named function instead:

```
function callHandler(){
    // invoking the handler here with arguments
    handler(this.style.color, this.style.backgroundColor);
}

domNode.addEventListener("click", callHandler);
```

To remove it you can then call `removeEventListener`:

```
domNode.removeEventListener('click', callHandler);
```